# Как запустить парсер в фоновом режиме?

Tags: php, joomla, парсер

Исходные данные:

1. Магазин на Joomla
2. Парсер, написанный на php

**Задача:** в админке создаётся кнопка, которая должна запускать парсер. Так как парсинг осуществляется длительное время (несколько часов), нужно его запустить в фоновом режиме, чтобы браузер можно было закрыть. При повторном нажатии на кнопку из админки должно бросать на страницу с индикатором, дескать, процесс уже запущен, ожидайте.

В идеале, если кроном уже запущено, то тоже индикатор должен отображать это.

Как все провернуть?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно где-то хранить этот индикатор запущенного процесса.

В *nix среде принято просто создавать файлик, напр., "parser.pid", в котором записано единственное число – номер запущенного процесса. Когда процесс завершается, он последним действием удаляет свой pid-файл.

Так же и вы можете, запуская парсер, создавать в условленном месте файл, в который писать id процесса – id можно получить прямо в php через [`getmypid()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getmypid.php).

В админке смотрите, есть ли такой файл, а ещё хорошо бы проверять, жив ли процесс с этим id: через выполнение shell-команды, или, если [не отключены](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/posix.installation.php) POSIX-функции, [`posix_kill( $pid, 0)`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.posix-kill.php). Последняя отправляет нулевой сигнал, который ничего не делает, процессу. Ф-я вернёт `true`, если удалось отправить, иначе `false`.

Так вы из любого места можете узнать, жив ли процесс. И дальше показывать, запускать и т.п. по логике своего приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю. Допустим я разберусь с индикатором. А собственно запуск в фоновом режиме как осуществить?

Comment: ответьте пожалуйста!

Comment: Например, можно ставить флаг "надо запустить" (создавать файл "parser.start" опять же), а запускаемая по крону раз в 5 минут задача, будет искать такой флаг, и если он найдётся, запускать процесс и удалять файл-флаг.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить следующий вариант: создаете отдельную таблицу в БД, в которой будет отображаться факт запуска парсера и некий индикатор выполнения парсинга, который будет обновляться в процессе. Соответственно при запуске парсера (по кнопке или крону) устанавливается флаг в БД. При последующем нажатии кнопки выполняется проверка запущен ли парсер уже. Если да - то просто отображается индикатор. По завершению парсинга флаг снимается.

Answer (score 0):

Mожете использовать `$_SESSION` для создания переменной. Потом используете её на подобие "мьютекса", для вашей индикации.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону PHP функции `ignore_user_abort`

Помещаете в цикл парсер, задаете в цикле sleep(нжуное время) активируете `ignore_user_abort` и даже когда вы закроете браузер парсер все равно будет работать до тех пор пока сам скрипт его не остановит или же сбой в работе PHP не произойдет и никаких кронов мронов не нужно!

Для записи результата можно создать .txt файла открыть его для записи и чтения и писать туда результат работы скрипта, а так же, заблокировать файл для повторной записи и легко можно будет понять, что парсер работает и брать оттуда соответствующий результат. Ну это то, что мне в голову сходу пришло, думаю, если хорошо пораскинуть головой, то можно найти решение получше